# Изменение данных в JSON файле

Tags: json, node.js

Имеется JSON файл с данными

```
{
 answer: "1883188"
}
```

И имеется бот написанный на `vk-io`. Как сделать так чтобы при изменении данных в JSON файле бот отправлял сразу же новую информацию

Comment: Смотрите в сторону fs watcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MoloF прав, fs.watcher() для этого в самый раз, для обьяснения подходит: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/360495/